# If ($condition_string) is not working properly

Tags: php

In the following code

```
$condition_string= "empty($_SESSION['group_by_Name']) && empty($_SESSION['group_by_Email']) && empty($_SESSION['group_by_Address']) && empty($_SESSION['group_by_Age']) && empty($_SESSION['group_by_Contact'])";
```

This code always execute if statement not else. can anybody tell me where is the error in my code.

```
   $observation_column_name_fetch = mysql_query("SELECT column_name
 FROM  observation_column where observation_id='$observation_id'")
     or die(mysql_error());

     while($observation_column_name_res = mysql_fetch_array( $observation_column_name_fetch ))
     {
      $observation_column_name[]=$observation_column_name_res[column_name];
     }   
     for ($i=0; $i<$observation_column_num; $i++)
     { 
      $group_by=$_POST[group_by_.$observation_column_name[$i]];
      $_SESSION[group_by_.$observation_column_name[$i]]=$group_by;
     }
     $j=1;
     $condition_string="";
     for($i=0; $i<$observation_column_num; $i++)
     {
     $condition_string.= 'empty($_SESSION[\'group_by_'.$observation_column_name[$i].'\'])';
     if($j<$observation_column_num)
      { $condition_string.=" && ";    $j++;    }
     }
     if($condition_string)
      {
      for ($i=0; $i<$observation_column_num; $i++)
        { echo "if statement executed ".$i." times<br/>";   }
      }
        else
        {
       for ($i=0; $i<$observation_column_num; $i++)
          { echo "else statement executed ".$i." times<br/>";        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make variable names dynamic:

```
if( empty( $_SESSION['group_by_' . $observation_column_name[$i] ] ){
    // ..code..
}
```

Comment: if statement has to be executed if all the session variable $_SESSION['group_by_Name'],  $_SESSION['group_by_Email'], $_SESSION['group_by_Address'], $_SESSION['group_by_Age'] and $_SESSION['group_by_Contact'] are empty.

If i use
if( empty( $_SESSION['group_by_' . $observation_column_name[$i] ] ){
    // ..code..
}

then if statement is executed if any of the session variable is empty

Comment: @Amrit I think you aren't choosing the best method for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a condition in a string representation to an if statement.  In your current code, you are simply checking that the string `$condition_string` **is not false**.

You must pass the condition in string form to the [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function to evaluate it as code.

Comment: I can not write the condition directly into the if statement because $observation_column_name[] is an array and $observation_column_num is variable which is fetched from database.

$observation_column_name[] and $observation_column_num are dynamically loaded from database. 

Is there any other solution???

Comment: eval("\$condition_string = \"$condition_string\";");
echo $condition_string;

**This returns :**
`empty(group_by_Name) && empty(group_by_Email) && empty(group_by_Address) && empty(group_by_Age) && empty(group_by_Contact)`


**Instead of this i want**
`empty($_SESSION[group_by_Name]) && empty($_SESSION[group_by_Email]) && empty($_SESSION[group_by_Address]) && empty($_SESSION[group_by_Age]) && empty($_SESSION[group_by_Contact])`